# Proving the convergence of an implictly-defined sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $f(\vec x|\vec \theta)$ be a function $f : \mathbb R^{N} \times \mathbb R^M \to \mathbb R^N$ which is interpreted to be a function parameterized by some $M$ parameters $\vec \theta = (\theta_1,\theta_2,\dots,\theta_M)$ which is applied to some tuple of $N$ numbers $\vec x = (x_1,x_2,\dots,x_N)$. Assume that for fixed $\vec \theta$, there is a unique $\vec x$ which solves $f(\vec x| \vec \theta) = 0$. Let $g(\vec \theta| \vec x)$ be some function $g: \mathbb R^M \times \mathbb R^N \to \mathbb R^M$  which takes in some parameters $\vec \theta$ and values $\vec x$ and outputs some new parameters.

Consider sequences $\vec x^{(0)},\vec x^{(1)}, \vec x^{(2)}, \dots$ and $\vec \theta^{(0)},\vec \theta^{(1)}, \vec \theta^{(2)},\dots$ which are defined by the recursive relations,
$$
\vec \theta^{(n+1)} = g(\vec \theta^{(0)}| \vec x^{(n)}),\\
\vec x^{(n+1)} \in \{\vec x : f(\vec x | \vec \theta^{(n+1)}) = 0\}.
$$ In words, $\theta^{(n+1)}$ is determined by $g$ applied to $\vec \theta^{(n)}$ given $x^{(n)}$, and $\vec x^{(n+1)}$ is the unique value of $\vec x$ that satisfies the equation $f(\vec x | \vec \theta^{(n+1)}) = 0$ with fixed $\vec \theta^{(n+1)}$.
The initial values $\vec x^{(0)}$, $\vec \theta^{(0)}$ are given.
Under what conditions does $$
\lim_{n \to \infty} f(\vec x^{(n)} | \vec \theta^{(0)}) = 0.
$$
More importantly, for a given form of $f$ and $g$ for which the above is true, how does one prove such convergence?

This problem (in a more concrete form) has arisen in my applied math research, and computational experiments have shown that such convergence exists robustly. I would like to present a proof of this for my choices of $f$ and $g$ in a way that does not rely on numerical analysis.

Any input is greatly appreciated. Thank you!